# Are OpenStreetmap related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are there any question about OpenStreetmap considered on-topic here? If so, what kind of question would be inside the scope?

Answer (score 9):

I think that unless the Questions are really basic and have to do with fundamental usage, we should Allow them here.

Comment: If they are GIS-related, I think they should even be allowed at a very basic level...

Answer (score 5):

We have a few [existing questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openstreetmap) about OSM, which I'd consider all to be on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

My feeling is that it would depend entirely on the question (e.g. "importing the data into arcgis" is going to be more on topic than "when should I use natural=wood vs landuse=forest")

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is relevant to the discussion now or not, but I just saw that the [help forum](http://help.openstreetmap.org/) for OSM looks pretty much like any other StackExchange site. Is this another stackexchange site, or have they copied the design of stack overflow?

Comment: It's running on "OSQA", an Open Source workalike based on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm surprised that I did not come across this sooner.  I think my policy on OSM (which I like to be very supportive of) will be to write (in longer form) "[**OSM Help Pages**](https://help.openstreetmap.org/) are likely to be your best bet for this question that is about OSM basics rather than how it integrates with, and is an important part of, GIS".

Comment: @PolyGeo: Maybe I'm missing something here, but did you mean to post this as an answer, rather than a comment?

Comment: As a comment - I was not aware of the SE like help for OSM until I came across it today. I was about to ask why the account I created was not linked to my SE accounts when I saw your Answer.